# How to make zoom-out on page or div on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have problem with make site to be able to zoom out.
When i set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` the page can be zoomed in but can`t be zoomed out. With adding maximum-scale and minimum scale I have the same problem. 
What should I do? 
My main goal is to is zoomable in and out (specially zoom-out) only one div (on mobile via gestures). Maybe somebody know where I can find script which do that or know the solution?

Comment: Why would you want to zoom out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand you correctly, you want to be able to "pinch" on specific element (e.g. div).

You can use `IScroll`.

http://lab.cubiq.org/zoom/

http://iscrolljs.com/#zoom

**Code & Demo (run it from mobile device)**

http://jsbin.com/luqifu

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: true,
    zoom:true
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width:320px;
  height:480px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iScroll/5.1.3/iscroll-zoom.js"></script>

<p>
  Image from <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin#/media/File:Dolphind.jpg">Wikipedia</a>
</p>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Dolphind.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide any example on jsfiddle where I can zoom-out and it will be saving position because what I`m getting is only zoom-in and when I zoom-out it`s backing to neutral position..

Comment: If the user do zoom-out what he will see in around of the div?

Comment: zoomed-out image because actually it`s scaled 1:1 so must have be able to zoom-out

Comment: The iScroll alow to zoom-out after you do zoom-in (in other words, you can zoom-out on image that disply in zoom-in)

Comment: Page is loaded with cut image on mobile, he now should can do zoom-out without back to after loaded zoomed position

Comment: Ok than. Iscroll allow this. Try it.

Comment: I did try. Where I can found jsfiddle with somethink like that?

Comment: His gestures are not such perfect. For example, when you zoom using two fingers, without releasing one finger you can continue doing pan on native apps, but not in iScroll.

Comment: You can contact with the author and report this.