# Allow to zoom in-out a div on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, zooming

I'm working on the mobile version of a page I created and I have a div with a table inside which is too wide for mobile.

I've already made it a scroll so it can be X-scrolled on mobile but I'd like to make it possible to zoom out, only that div/table.

Is there any CSS code that can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, this link may be of use:

[How to make zoom-out on page or div on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188870/how-to-make-zoom-out-on-page-or-div-on-mobile)

However, the zooming is done with **Javascript**, not CSS.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as correct since as you said it looks like there's no css method to do that and it's what I was looking for.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TraaZ Thanks! Yes I don't believe you will find any information about zooming on mobile without the use of JS. JavaScript allows for a programmer to execute functions on the occurrence of certain events using a DOM event listener.