# How to enable zoom on a div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the mobile version of a page I created and I have a div with an owl carousel

On the mobile version, all pages could apply the zoom, except this div.

Is there any CSS to enable zoom on certain divs?

The items that could not be zoomed is styled with this:

```
.episodeslist-home .item {
    margin: 12px 0px 20px 0px;
    width: 202.2px;
    height: 152.3px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: You should post the HTML structure as well. Also, what happened to the precision of the width & height? quite weird

Comment: I just use a div with contain .item, not css applied to this div. i think is something from owl carousel but i don't know what..

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188870/how-to-make-zoom-out-on-page-or-div-on-mobile)

Comment: I tried this, not work.. i think its a carrousel bug: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2395